# Chain actions and animations in a sequence

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, sequence

In Cocos2D, we use CCSequence to chain actions/animations and whatever in a sequence.
Like:

1. Move (animate) image from top left of screen to bottom right of screen over 5 seconds. (we just enter the start and end locations of the image, Cocos2D takes care of tweening the location over time)
2. Delay/wait the sequence 2.5 seconds
3. Move that image again to centre of screen while scaling it up to 1.5 size over 3 seconds.
4. Then have a block called on completion so that we can continue with some other code...

This way it's very easy to chain actions up with probably 4-6 lines of code. How do we do that in Unity? I am using Unity 4.6 and am so far only using 2D elements.

Comment: Lookup Coroutines and you will find a method that returns an IEnumerator. This method can utilise the "WaitForSeconds (float s)" class, which does exactly what it says lol… If you look at the Tween question you asked, you will see my answer. If you replace "yield return 0;" with "yield return new WaitForSeconds (1.0f);" You will see that it executes the Lerp function then waits for 1.0 second. It will then run the code again and again and until it reaches its destination. You can duplicate this method to scale etc etc…

Answer (score 3):

```
IEnumerator Sequence()
{
  yield return Move();
  yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.5f);
  yield return MoveScaling;
  yield return OnComplete();
}
...
StartCoroutine(Sequence());
```

This is more ore less what the code will look like. I let to you the implementation of the single subroutine. To get more info have a look at how [Unity coroutine](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) work (they are simply [C#'s iterator blocks](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter6/iteratorblockimplementation.aspx))